# Why openoffice and libreoffice are very slow on saving odt file on windows 7 and 8

Tags: windows, performance, save, openoffice.org, libreoffice

When I save a native file .odt with openoffice or libreoffice, the software takes several seconds before being enable again. Otherwise, when I save .xsl file with both softwares, it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to remove the file content indexation on the hard drive:
- right mouse click on the hard drive
- select properties
- unset "Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties"
- push "OK" button
- accept that directories and subdirectories are unset
- wait